# Reverse the string in C++

Tags: c++, reverse, stdstring

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

main() 
{
beginning:
    string name;
    cout << "Hey! Enter your name" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    int i = name.length() - 1;
    do
    {
        cout << name[i];
        i--;
    } while (i > -1);
    cout << " Your reverse name is " << name[i] << endl;
    cout << name[i] << " Your reverse name is " << endl;
    goto beginning;
}
```

[image]

1. Why the *"zsuidakrA"* is being displayed before  *"Your reverse name
   is"* although I have coded like `cout<<" Your reverse name is "<<name[i]<<endl;`
2. For `cout<<name[i]<<" Your reverse name is "<<endl;` this line, I
   have found only *"Your reverse name is"* but there is no name. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: What you have done is not called "reversing a string". It is called "printing a string in reverse order". When you reverse a string, you start with a string and end up with a different string. You don't print anything in process. If you want to test what you have done, you print the new string normally as you would print any other string.

Answer (score 6):

You are first displaying the reverse string, then outputting `Your reverse name is`. But the string is never reversed. Use:

```
string reverse_name(name.rbegin(), name.rend())
```

to create the reverse string.

Then display it using `cout`.

Just an FYI, don't use `goto`s...

Comment: Do you refer to std::reverse ? Because in that case it has a void return type. [CPP Ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Comment: No, it was just a new variable, sorry, changed the name.

Answer (score 3):

You could use std::reverse to reverse it for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm> // std::reverse

int main(){
    std::string name;
    while(true) {
        std::cout << "Hey! Enter your name: " << std::flush;
        std::cin >> name;
        std::cout << "Your name is: " << name << "\n";
        std::reverse(begin(name), end(name));
        std::cout << "Your reverse name is: " << name << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the last two cout statements. 
The reverse string is already printed by the cout statement inside the do-while loop. You can move the

```
cout<<" Your reverse name is "<<endl;
```

before the do statement if that is really required..

Answer (score 1):

1) because you are printing name[i] in do while loop before your cout statement.

2) because value of i = -1 after it comes out of do while loop as ( i > -1) condition gets false, and name[-1] is probably printing nothing.

Comment: In C++ be careful about index values.